# Python: Splitting a 1-D Columnar Array into Several Columns

Tags: python, arrays

I have a created an array from text file data that has elements that look like this:

```
19480101 22.4  2.24
19490101 33.1  3.31
```

However, each of these rows is just one element in the array. This results in the array being a 1-D column. How can I split it up at the whitespaces to create an array with 3 columns instead of one?

Comment: Do you know about `.split()` method?

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If so, please check the _tick_ to the left of my answer (so that does not show up in unanswered Q). If not, please specify, what do you need.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method on string:

```
print('19480101 22.4  2.24'.split())    
print('19490101 33.1  3.31'.split())
# outputs
['19480101', '22.4', '2.24']
['19490101', '33.1', '3.31']
```